# Blank line in email headers causes Postfix to skip remaining lines

Tags: postfix, smtp-headers

I have a daily email that comes in to one user in which the headers of the email contain a blank line.  This is causing mail clients/webmail to display "Invalid address" "Unknown date" and no subject.  When I analyze the headers at mxtoolbox I'm able to remove the blank line and all the information gets displayed properly.  Typically I would just let the user know that the sender needs to fix the headers in this automatically generated email but they've tested with external mail providers (gmail, yahoo, etc) and the information that is missing from the server I manage gets displayed properly on these other providers.  I've searched around a little and either I haven't found an answer for how to get Postfix to ignore this blank line or I'm not understanding what I need to do.

Is there a setting somewhere I can adjust or anything that I can do on my end to deal with these blank lines in the header?  Here are the headers causing the problem:

```
Return-Path: <xxx@xxx.com>
X-Original-To: yyy@yyy.com
Delivered-To: yyy@yyy.com
Received: from aaa.bbb.ccc.net (aaa.bbb.ccc.net [1.2.3.4])
        by ddd.eee.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id E794FA0D80
        for <yyy@yyy.com>; Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:20:52 -0500 (CDT)
Authentication-Results: ddd.eee.net;
        spf=none (sender IP is 1.2.3.4) smtp.mailfrom=zzz@zzz.com smtp.helo=aaa.bbb.ccc.net
Received-SPF: none (ddd.eee.net: no valid SPF record)
Received: from ZZZ ([5.6.7.8])
        by :SMTPAUTH: with ESMTPA
        id 2FrYiJmwHSd922FrYiuWeV; Mon, 26 Aug 2019 07:20:52 -0700
X-Sender: zzz@zzz.com

Sent Date: 8/26/2019 9:20:52 AM
From: "ZZZ" <aaa@aaa.com>
Subject: XXXX
To: yyy@yyy.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="gr55wSFzBdfryST3lATLMCuIGHiYB=_Y1r"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: "ZZZ" <zzz@zzz.com>
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:20:52 -0500
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfFtIBmWvnzKW8FZldCXQTnRrNs1/ipatxzl4/hx3OnHZrpXqST8o8g8A1UyVUbWDC6J4KGR/NS9qqskutLJqJvorLFbLQRGFKgl08uLmnXVsktqvD4barOrXXsyzXFiyqc26910WAlGk0x1WVgMGX8SDtGRy/ZnSe/mqL3tDP6Yjsejw8C2JZZFU1tsMvs4SHgWrohLeqDCN6YcEVOaxn10=
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal and cannot be adjusted. The headers are separated from the body by an empty line. Thus, everything after an empty line is treated as the body. From [RFC 5322, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1):

> The header section is a sequence of lines of characters with special
> syntax as defined in this specification. The body is simply a sequence
> of characters that follows the header section and is separated from
> the header section by an empty line* (i.e., a line with nothing
> preceding the CRLF).

Messages having empty lines between the headers are malformed. This is a problem of the one sending the mail.